# enable vt-x in bios lenovo desktop

Tags: bios, android-virtual-device, uefi

I have a new Lenovo desktop, while I'm trying to run avd on android studio I get:

```
Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
VT-x is disabled in BIOS.

Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to the documentation for your computer).
```

I have tried everything :

`restart > F2 / restart > del / restart > F10`

It seems like my computer doesn't have the advanced options.

Comment: Did you try referring to the documentation for your computer (as suggested in the error message)?

Comment: yes i did, but i couldn't enter the advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

it is quite depends on what kind of board you bought. if you did not see in UEFI BIOS. there is no way to enable it. please post your h/w configuration. let me provide some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the bios of your ThinkPad (T430 in my case)
2. Go to Security > Memory Protection
3. Set "Execute Disable" to "Enabled".

With T430 you enter the bios with "Enter" and then F1.